# Extract text from html using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following html that is contained in my webpage.

```
<div id="flashmessage" class="ok">
     <a class="ico-close">x</a>
     MY TEXT HERE
</div>
```

How to extract 'MY TEXT HERE' from this html using jquery?

Note: I intend to convert this flashmessage to fancybox popup.

Comment: Here is full example : https://jsfiddle.net/sur08Lbv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just `clone` the `div` which contains text and `remove` all its children and then get the `text`. Snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text=$("#flashmessage").clone().children().remove().end().text();
    $(".result").text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flashmessage" class="ok">
     <a class="ico-close">x</a>
     MY TEXT HERE
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```